# problema con e.preventDefault() usando Ajax en Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Tengo un formulario que envia por ajax pero no guarda la informacion en la BD cuando activo e.preventDefault(); si la comento si la guarda.

EL Ajax es:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    }); 

    $("#enviar").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var codigo = $('#codigo').val();
        var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
        var ip = $('#ip').val();
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url: 'control',
           data:{
               codigo: codigo, 
               tipo: tipo, 
               ip: ip},
           success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
           }
        });
    });
```

El controlador es:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request->All());

    $control = new Control();
    $control->identification = $request->codigo;
    $control->type = $request->tipo;
    $control->date = date("Y/m/d");
    $control->time = date("h:i:s");
    $control->ip = $request->ip;
    $control->save();
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Got Simple Ajax Request.']);
}
```

Las rutas son:

```
Route::get('/control', 'ControlController@index');
Route::post('/control/store', 'ControlController@store');
```

Estoy usando la version 5.7 de laravel no se si falta alguna librería, ya intente los tutoriales que veo en youtube actualizados y son los mismos que siempre he usado.

Comment: Cuando no está comentada dicha línea, ¿ejecuta las otras líneas de JavaScript?

Comment: Podrias mostrar el html tambien

Answer (score 0):

en el modelo has agregado esos campos? algo asi

```
protected $fillable = ['identification', 'type','date','time','ip',];
```

luego verificar si tienes campos que no aceptan null

Comment: no veo relación entre los `protected` y el hecho del fallo con `preventDefault` explícate por favor

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente al momento de hacer la petición con ajax no se este enviando el csrf-token, por eso al momento de comentar el e.preventDefault(); estas indicando que la pagina si se recargue, con lo cual el token si se envia al backend, ademas la url debe estar indicada como la declaraste en el archivo web control/store, el codigo quedaria algo asi:

```
$("#enviar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var codigo = $('#codigo').val();
    var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
    var ip = $('#ip').val();
    $.ajax({
      headers: {
        //Prueba cual de las dos formas te funcionan
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
      },
       type:'POST',
       url: 'control/store',
       data:{
           codigo: codigo, 
           tipo: tipo, 
           ip: ip},
       success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: revisa bien el inicio del código de quien pregunta y ahi se muestra como envia el token

Comment: Si lo note, pero probablemente el meta al que hace referencia para traer el csrf-token no este en el head, si no el cuerpo del formulario, por eso al momento de quitar el codigo javascript que hace que la pagina no se recargue, funciona porque todos los inputs, incluso los ocultos se envian al backend, no asi en la peticion ajax.

Answer (score 0):

1. Si el botón con el id "#enviar" es de tipo submit, al quitar el preventDefault() es posible que se este ejecutando el form html y no el ajax, cambialo a type="button"
2. El url de tu ajax esta mal, debería ser 'control/store'.
3. Asegurate de tener bien configurado la etiqueta  dentro del  con el token csrf en tu layout (vista principal)

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```